# Where are ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} and ${PRODUCT_NAME} defined

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, plist

Where can I find information on how to modify these

- `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}`
- `${PRODUCT_NAME}`

These are only displayed in .plist file but where are the actual values.

If we can directly modify what ever we want in .plist why we need these.

I am new that's why I'm having problem understanding these, I also looked into apple information Property list key reference but didn't find these ${} values.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can change these values through command line tools if you use an [xcconfig](https://nshipster.com/xcconfig/). ie you set them to whatever you want and then archive and release a build

Answer (score 201):

The `PRODUCT_NAME` is defined in the target's `Build Settings` in the `Packaging` section. It has the same name by default as your project.

[image: screenshot]

**Edit:**

While `PRODUCT_NAME` is by default the name of the Target (`MyDemoApp` in this case). The `EXECUTABLE_NAME` is a concatenation of:

`$EXECUTABLE_PREFIX`, `$PRODUCT_NAME` and `$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX`.

See the reference of [EXECUTABLE_NAME](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW71) for details.

### Update

The new reference can be found here http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.3/#/itcaec37c2a6

> **`EXECUTABLE_NAME`**
>   Specifies the name of the binary the target produces.

Comment: Opps, my `Product Name`'s default value is `$(TARGET_NAME)`, though it is equal to my project name..

Comment: So where is the $(TARGET_NAME) stored?

Comment: @Jim Thio: This is the name on your Target which you can change by clicking on the target in the view above. By default the target has the same name as the project so in my example the name of the target is "MyDemoApp" too.

Comment: @Besi can we access buildSettings file to make some changes manually when project is not opened in xcode like build.xml in android

Comment: @Hercules Have a look at your `-Info.plist` file, some of the values are defined in there and can therefore be changed without opening Xcode

Comment: Where do you see that `EXECUTABLE_NAME` is a concatenation of:
`$EXECUTABLE_PREFIX`, `$PRODUCT_NAME` and `$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the $ represents the variable productName & executableName as the $ is used in unix. The variables are set in the build setting of the application. So you should not change the product name directly in the plist file. Instead, go to build settings, search for product name and change it.

Comment: in build settings i am able to see only product name other executable variable is not there

Comment: It's worth noting that you can change these values through command line tools if you use an [xcconfig](https://nshipster.com/xcconfig/). ie you set them to whatever you want and then archive and release a build

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode `${<variable_name>}` syntax**

Xcode variable can be defined on different level and the `Resolved` one is used. You can use `Build Settings -> Levels` tab to manage it

[image]

All variables are listen in [`Build Settings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW105). Also every setting has it's own declaration

```
Product Name - PRODUCT_NAME
```

These setting are saved in `buildSettings` block of

```
<project_name>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

You can use Search view to find any variable and `Help Inspector` to find declaration and other useful information

[image]

Some of settings are not exposed by Xcode

```
EXECUTABLE_NAME
```

But you are able to get or even to override the value using `User-Defined Settings`

[image]

```
reader_EXECUTABLE_NAME = $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
```

```
EXECUTABLE_NAME = $EXECUTABLE_PREFIX$PRODUCT_NAME$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX
```

[[SWIFT_MODULE_NAME, PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME, EXECUTABLE_NAME]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611724/how-to-modify-swift-module-name/57517400#57517400)

[[TARGET_NAME]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348473/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically about how `${PRODUCT_NAME}` gets defined in terms of order:

1. It's originally defaulted to the target's name: `$(TARGET_NAME)`
2. You can reset it in 'build settings' by searching for **Product Name**

Note: If any value was derived off of `${PRODUCTS_NAME}` and you change it to `some-constant-value` then it's no longer going to be a computed value.

e.g. if you change the value of `CFBundleName` from its default `${PRODUCT_NAME}` to something like `My cool App` then your app's name on the springboard will show up as 'My cool App'. It will no longer show up as 'whatever your target's name is'