# iOS changing target name

Tags: ios, xcode

In iOS project, I changed the target name.
But for building, on the top left (beside stop button), its still showing old target name only... What should I change so that old project name will completely disappear from XCode?

Comment: Help ! How did you change the target name ?

Comment: @Cherif, its just as per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[image: Manage Schemes]

[image: Set Name]

Just Click on your target Name beside stop button > Manage Schemes > Select and change name

[image: Altered Name]

Comment: @downvoter Can you please point what is the mistake in above steps :-| so that I can improve. At-least mention reason why you feel this to down vote?

Comment: This does not change the name of the App seen on the home-screen!

Answer (score 47):

Select your target from TARGETS(in left navigation bar) and double click, then rename it.

[image]

Comment: the most useful answer

Comment: Took me a while to figure this out (don't judge me) - but if anyone else is struggling to get to this view -> Next to the "General" button (on the left) is the button that hides/shows the tree view that allows you to rename the TARGETS. Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: That, or the small little icon to the left of General does the trick also.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to change Project Name, Target name, -Info.plist name & -Prefix.pch name then,

```
    - Select Project in Xcode (.xcodeproj file)
    - Selecte file inspector
    - In identity section change project name which u want to update & press enter
    - After scanning whole project it will ask to change the file names i.e target, plist & pch file
    - Select check boxes as per your need
```

Comment: I believe this is the better answer to the question.

Comment: So how to handle `.temp_caseinsensitive_rename` thing? This solution does not cover case-change-only modifications to the project name.

Answer (score 8):

**Target name(TARGET_NAME)**

To change a `Target name(TARGET_NAME)` you can:

- Rename a `target` via `Project Settings`(Double click or press Return)

[image]

Also after changing Target Name you can:

- Rename a `schema` via `Manage Schemas...` -> Select -> Press Return

[image]

- Rename a root `Group` via `Navigator`. In this case you should resolve errors that can be caused by out-to-date path. For example:

  - `Info.plist`(INFOPLIST_FILE) or

    ```
    Build input file cannot be found: '<some_path>/Info.plist'
    ```
  - `Bridging Header`(SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER) or

    ```
    error opening input file '<some_path>/<module_name>-Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)
    ```
  - Move umbrella header from private to public scope or

    ```
    Umbrella header '<name>.h' not found
    ```

[image]

[[Xcode components]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877)

Answer (score 6):

To make the change of target name effective you can go to manage schemes and there, remove all old targets. Then click on "Autocreate Schemes Now"