# How do I run a preferred target in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, targets

I'm studying a simple application demo from Apple that has two (2) targets.

Each target has its own plist, storyboard and some code; with a few files shared between them.

Choosing the 'R'un, runs one default target.   I want to specify what target to run.

How do I select the target to run in Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have more than one app target, you have more than one scheme. If you have more than one scheme, you can pick a scheme from the scheme menu (at the top of the project window). Then when you run, that scheme will be what builds and runs (on the corresponding destination).

In this screen shot, I have two app targets and hence two schemes ("backgroundPlayer" and "interrupter"):

[image]

As you can see, "backgroundPlayer" is checked. So if I build and run now, I build and run "backgroundPlayer". But if I choose "interrupter", then it will be checked, so if I then build and run, I build and run "interrupter".

Comment: Spot on.  So simple. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You might want to read the section of my book explaining what a scheme is: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html#_schemes_and_destinations

Answer (score -1):

Every target has 0 or more schemas

Xcode v10

`Product -> Scheme -> Choose Scheme`
//or
`control` + `0`
//or
click on the active scheme

[image]

Here you can manage your schemas

[[Xcode project structure]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215808/4770877)