# How to switch the build for iOS app

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6

My application support 20 languages such as: English, German, French, Danish ...
Now I want to build 2 version:
1. English only
2. Full 20 languages.

Must I have to create 2 separate projects in order to build 2 IPA file?

I am using Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to do this?

Comment: We have to build 2 versions with difference server URL : for USA only and for Worldwide

Comment: So why do you need to strip out all other languages for the USA version?

Comment: This is the requirement from my customer, they want to remove unnecessary languages.

Comment: You can create different buid schema or target. You can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637435/xcode-what-is-a-target-and-scheme-in-plain-language)

Comment: My question about schema or target is: can I change the URL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate your target then add a key (YOUR_KEY=1) in `Target` > `Build Settings` > `Preprocessor Macros`.

[image]

Now you can use `#if #else #endif` to define url for 2 targets.

```
#if English
#define kUrl @"https://english.example.com"
#else
#define kUrl @"https://world.example.com"
#endif
```