# Why in iOS Framework, xctest is always red colour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xctest

I'm trying to make a new framework to use in my other project. I know if it is red colour means can not find to the path of the file. But this not a file I created!

What I don't understand is why my new framework with pretty much nothing inside is always red colour. I even run test cases (default). I appreciate if anyone can help me to fix this:

[image]

Comment: Select the Device option and build it again. It should work. Items listed under `Products` group are reference to device target files not for simulator

Comment: I already did that. That is why the other one is black!

Comment: hmm, can you check in your scheme under _Build_ option if test target has tick mark against _Analyze_, _Test_ and _Run_ options. If this doesn't solve it then i am our of ideas.

Comment: @Gandalf Do you mean schema means my targets? Could you be more specific. I can't find it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *Scheme*(not schema) is different from *Target*. Check out this thread for better understanding [Xcode: What is a target and scheme in plain language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637435/xcode-what-is-a-target-and-scheme-in-plain-language)

To solve your issue, click on the *WSBandKit* framework icon on top left section(adjacent to iPad2 simulator icon); and select `editScheme` option from drop down. You will be presented with a new screen with some option. Go to Build option and tick the option of `Run` for your test target. Close the screen and Build the framework for Device.
Check the image for reference. Initially the `Run` option will be unchecked for test target that you have to check. [image]

Comment: Checking the Run checkbox did not make the red .xctest file turn black. I have three projects. One produces the expected .xctest file (it is black). The other two do not. The one that does is a framework. The other two are applications. Might that possibly explain why XCTest cannot produce a test framework for those two projects? If so, is there any way to tell Xcode not to expect them? They don't seem to cause any actual problems. I can build and run the unit tests.