# How to manage multiple projects in single project copy in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

We have projects which are same for all the cities now I want to make those project in one project, so I can do a change in single project and effected in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create one different target for every city, on the same project. 
They will have the same core code and then, you can configure different ressources for all of them. (icons, images, fonts ...)

Each of them can use a different plist file in order to have some flags and not others.

To create a new target :
* Go to your project panel (with tabs General - Capabilities - Resources tag ...)
* Open the left panel
* There is a + at the bottom to create your new target (or you can copy an existing one)

You can switch from a target to another on the top bar at the right of the selected device to debug

When you have a file, you can decide on which target he can go on the right panel on the section "Target Membership"

Need screenshots ?

Comment: Nicely explained Phoenix. No need screenshots yet. Let you know if any issue faced in future. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice explained with pictures is [here](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/using_xcode_targets.html).
You can achieve it by using [targets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) in Xcode.

As well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637435/xcode-what-is-a-target-and-scheme-in-plain-language) is explained about targets.