# How to modify SWIFT_MODULE_NAME?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

The title says it all. I've searched in the build settings for **SWIFT_MODULE_NAME**, and nothing came up. I've also searched online, and there are references to this name, but there is no information on how it is defined. *Furthermore, I couldn't find any mention of SWIFT_MODULE_NAME in the Apple Docs.*

I do know this: it is used in the "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name" build setting, and can be viewed by double-clicking on the settings value:

> $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h

It is used to bridge the gap between Objective-C and Swift, and appears only for projects that include Swift files, (along with Objective-C files I presume). As of this posting, Xcode 7.3 is the latest and greatest.

But, where is this value defined, and how do I modify it?

Comment: Have you checked out this doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID138 ? usually it is your product name. You can set change the value in "Product Bundle Identifier" in Build Settings. Note you can not override a product name in a Framework

Comment: Yes that's helpful, thanks. From that doc: "Xcode uses your product module name (PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)—not your target name (TARGET_NAME)—when naming the Objective-C bridging header and the generated header for your Swift code."

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The module name comes from the Product Module Name build setting:

[image: build settings screenshot]

The `SWIFT_MODULE_NAME` setting is apparently hidden, but you can see its derivation by looking at `Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XCLanguageSupport.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/Swift.xcspec`:

```
...
{
    Name = "SWIFT_MODULE_NAME";
    Type = String;
    DefaultValue = "$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)";
    CommandLineArgs = (
        "-module-name",
        "$(value)",
    );
},
...
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I changed the PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME, and the SWIFT_MODULE_NAME was updated!

Comment: Oh my,  4 hours looking for this - debated the concept of retirement.  Xcode Version 9.4 (9F1027a) had filled it blank from a fresh swift project create 3 days ago.  I will post a possible bug.  ouch!    don't forget #import "MsbHrv-Swift.h" in the .m, for every function on swift object that your accessing put the "@objc" in front of the declaration in the .swift file, and make sure this SWIFT_MODULE_NAME is set in the PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME.  OR just build everything in swift, be happy, and pet puppies to calm your day.

Comment: Please note that Product Module Name defaults to using ```$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)``` so the best place to change this is to ensure that you set PRODUCT_NAME or "Product Name" to a value and all will update accordingly.

Comment: To follow up on Dino's observation: There's yet another step, because PRODUCT_NAME is defined as $(TARGET_NAME).  But... it dead-ends there. I can't find TARGET_NAME in any of the settings; maybe Xcode only shows it in the project navigator (left pane). One more thing: If your project or product name is hyphenated, Xcode will replace the hyphen with an underscore. This will cause builds to fail if you explicitly refer to the $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h file's expected name anywhere.

Answer (score 8):

**SWIFT_MODULE_NAME, PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME, EXECUTABLE_NAME**

Default values:

```
EXECUTABLE_NAME = $EXECUTABLE_PREFIX$PRODUCT_NAME$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX
SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME = $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME) 

SWIFT_MODULE_NAME = $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)
PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME = $(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)
PRODUCT_NAME = $(TARGET_NAME:c99extidentifier)
```

Observation:

```
SWIFT_MODULE_NAME == PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME
```

**c99extidentifier**

Xcode is able to substitute a value of variable
`c99extidentifier` identifier which supports extended characters from [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)

```
//for example
PRODUCT_NAME = My Framework
PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME = $(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier) = My_Framework
```

`EXECUTABLE_NAME` name of binary

`Product Module Name(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)` determines how the `import` statement will look like. For example when you are creating a `Library` or a `Framework`.

Using:

```
//Objective-C
@import module_name; 

//Swift
import module_name
```

`Product Name(PRODUCT_NAME)` determines the name of binary. E.g. MyFramework.framework

[image]

[[TARGET_NAME]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348473/4770877)

Rule is:

```
SWIFT_MODULE_NAME should equal to PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME
```

[[Custom .modulemap]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704268/no-umbrella-header-found-for-target-module-map-will-not-be-generated/57665560#57665560)

Answer (score 6):

Go to build Settings and click + next to 'Levels'.
See :

[image]

replace NEW_SETTING as SWIFT_MODULE_NAME for the name of the setting, and whatever is the module name for .h file (No spaces, please) goes on the right.

Comment: Hit the plus sign for add user defined settings was the part i missed at first.

Comment: Added SWIFT_MODULE_NAME and fixed my unit tests on XCode 9 because our module name has a "-" in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this doc: developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/… ? usually it is your product name. You can set change the value in "Product Bundle Identifier" in Build Settings. Note you can not override a product name in a Framework

See the screenshot:

[image]