# Conversion to Swift 5 produces 'Multiple commands produce x86_64.swiftmodule' error

Tags: swift5, xcode10.2

I am trying to get Xcode 10.2 to convert my hybrid Objective-C / Swift project to use Swift 5. Whenever I do this, however, the compilation files due to the following error

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/<User>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurgEval-chcbdqcuvbtwckedraqzdhwbsqpm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/SurgEval/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule':
1) Target 'MYAPPTests' (project 'SurgEval'): Ditto /Users/alenox/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurgEval-chcbdqcuvbtwckedraqzdhwbsqpm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/SurgEval/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule /Users/<User>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurgEval-chcbdqcuvbtwckedraqzdhwbsqpm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/SurgEval/Intermediates.noindex/SurgEval.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPPTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MYAPP.swiftmodule
2) Target 'SurgEval' (project 'SurgEval'): Ditto /Users/<User>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurgEval-chcbdqcuvbtwckedraqzdhwbsqpm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/SurgEval/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPPL.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule /Users/<User>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurgEval-chcbdqcuvbtwckedraqzdhwbsqpm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/SurgEval/Intermediates.noindex/SurgEval.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SurgEval.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MYAPP.swiftmodule
```

I have already tried switching to using the 'Legacy Build System' as suggested in other similar questions, but I would like to migrate to the new build system.

I have also tried to change the product module name in my test target as suggested in another question, but that broke my tests.

The application and tests both build and run fine otherwise, I just get a compilation error while running the Swift 5 migration tool.

Any idea what's going on here, or some some docs I can look at to better understand this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to partly solve this issue by adjusting SWIFT_MODULE_NAME property in Test target.

My test's target SWIFT_MODULE_NAME was same as main target name, so i changed it

Comment: To change the module name, use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611724/how-to-modify-swift-module-name