# No such module "MyApp" in Core Data generated extension files

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I changed the "Display Name" of my App. But, after that, I cannot build the application successfully anymore. I keep getting the below error in the file `Attachment+CoreDataProperties.swift` which was automatically generated by Xcode:

```
No such module 'MyApp'
```

Provided that 'MyApp' is my application name.
I tried cleaning the project and deleting the DerivedData folder with no success. I also renamed the project to the old name when it used to work. But, still no success.

Any help on how to debug further would be appreciated.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611724/how-to-modify-swift-module-name. It might help you to find the module name. Also try changing Codegen of each entity in your data model file from Category/Extension to Manual/None and try changing back to Category/Extension. May be this might help.

Comment: Maybe this solution might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418989 also read through the comments.

Comment: Thanks guys, I went through the answers and comments but nothing helped. At the end, I created a new project and moved the files to it.