# Where does Xcode store ${PRODUCT_NAME} on the file system?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcodebuild

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723164/where-are-executable-name-and-product-name-defined) where it was asked where to find ${PRODUCT_NAME} in Xcode itself, I would like to know where (so in which file) Xcode stores the value of the ${PRODUCT_NAME} on the file system?

I want to write a build script that is able to automatically access this variable and change the product name without using Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj.

Although in this case you'll probably find you're better served by not actually changing the PRODUCT_NAME, but by changing whatever it is you're using PRODUCT_NAME for.  Even then you'll probably find that the best approach is to use an .xcconfig file, which has a public format instead of the pbxproj file which has a rather arcane NextStep format.

Comment: Agree with above re: modifying project file. If you are using `xcodebuild` in your build script and need to override PROJECT_NAME, you can also just do it on the command line.  Like `xcodebuild -workspace <workspace> -scheme <scheme> PROJECT_NAME=<projectname>`. (NOTE: at the end, not before the command).

Comment: no. productName is per target and can even default to targetName so except it is somewhere in that file, this doesnt apply. opal's answer is better

Answer (score 2):

On Xcode 9.0 you can go to your main project settings > Build Settings and in the search bar find **Product Name**.

You will have an input field to change this value.