# Product Bundle Identifier name to apply in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I was looking into tutorials about how to build an iOS app with react native and firebase, and they always get the bundle iOS. In my case, since i'm using windows, i went to the *project.pbxproj* file and search for bundle and found this.

```
 PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)";
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                TEST_HOST = "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/firebase.app/firebase";
```

Usually in the product_bundle_identifier, they only have like **"org.reactjs.native.example"**.
Do you think I have to delete what comes after the dollar sign, or i can just put "org.reactjs.native.example" on the firebase and it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* modify anything about that `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER`. Well... OK, maybe you can, but there's no need for it. What you have there are the instructions of how Xcode builds the the final bundle ID, so you can replay them to get the same value.

Look up what your `PRODUCT_NAME` is (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693261/where-does-xcode-store-product-name-on-the-file-system) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723164/where-are-executable-name-and-product-name-defined/8972289)) and then funnel that through a `rfc1034identifier` "filter" (pretty much replacing spaces and dots with `_`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468176/should-the-rfc1034identifier-be-removed-from-the-cfbundleidentifier-in-plist-file/2468382#2468382) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173472/xcode-info-plist-build-variable-product-namerfc1034identifier-seems-complete). That will give you the final bundle ID that you need to specify in Firebase.