# Apple Mach-O Linker Error. Id: file not found... .app

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

This is doing my head in!! I've found related posts here but not my exact problem.

In the file inspector I changed the name (under Identity and Type) from "LiveVideo" to "Barnvisor". After that I'm not able to run the app i the iOS simulator.

It says "Build Failed" and I get the "Apple MAch-O Linker Error. linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". And it says: ld: file not found: /Users/johangrip/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Barnvisor-fzxomzatehfetsfqluxenxerhxov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LiveVideo.app/LiveVideo

What to do? :(

Comment: Have you tried doing a full clean of your project ? (`Cmd + Shift + K`)

Comment: yes. even downloaded some kind of xcode-cleaning program called watchdog. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand WHAT name you did change (you mention file inspector, but this can be ANY file)...The XCodeProj ? The target ? It seems you have some inconsistency in your naming, and XCode's complaining about that. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I think i changed the project name. When the error came up I tried to change it back, and when that didn't work I tried to change the name again, everywhere i could find the old one.I also think the problem is with inconsistency. Was worried somethiong would happen when i changed name so I saved a copy of my whole project folder beforehand, but everything seems to be linked to the computer so that didn't do much good.

Comment: You might find what you want here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723164/where-are-executable-name-and-product-name-defined

Comment: It's not an advanced app so I guees it will work to create it again from scratch by copy-paste the code from the corrupted projekt!? And this time set the right name from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you changed the name of your target, make sure the "test" name is also changed. Click on the target on the top of the left pane in Xcode, the one that scrolls. Make sure you change it to the test target now. That is, if your project is called "MyGameApp," go to "MyGameAppTest." I solved this by changing (in "General") the host application from Custom to "MyGameApp."